# Regression with a feature which has its own depth

Tags: regression, feature-selection, feature-extraction, feature-construction

I'm relatively new to ML/Statistical Analysis, and I'm facing a dataset structured like this

```
person_id, pay, task, hours
1, 560, A, 3
1, 560, B, 5
2, 650, A, 7
3, 520, C, 6
3, 520, A, 2
...
```

meaning person 1 is cumulatively paid 560 to perform task A 3 hrs and task B 5 hrs; person 2 paid 650 for task A 7 hrs; person 3 paid 520 for task C 6 hrs and A 2 hrs, etc. I hope it's clear.

I'd like to perform a regression, where my X plane is (task, hours) and Y is the per-person pay, but I haven't figured out yet how to approach such a problem. My tool box would be based on python+scikit-learn, preferably. But a generic discussion would be useful as well.

This is like

```
person_id, pay, tasks
[1, 560, [[A, 3], [B, 5]]
[2, 650, [[A, 7]]
[3, 520, [[C, 6], [A, 2]]
...
```

where *person_id* is a high cardinality feature which can be easily neglected, the Y label is *pay*, while the *tasks* (X) feature has its own structure, with fixed shape (2 dimensions here), but not a predetermined "depth", although limited in size (maybe 5-10 possible different tasks). I can't understand how to fit this in a regression schema, with such a structured feature data. Should I "flatten" *tasks* out, by explicitly having all possible values (A hours, B hours, C hours,... etc) as different columns, or is a more general approach possibile?

Moreover, this is a simplified version of my problem, to make the description simple enough, but it could include even more dimensions in the *tasks* structure, in which case the number of "flattened" task features would easily explode, to account for all possible combinations.

Any help welcome and appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on the non-simplified case: How many distinct tasks? Do the task-groupings have any structure? (e.g. "A & B go together usually", "B & C do not go together usually")

Comment: Hi @GeoMatt22 - actually not any such structures I can predict. The non-simplified case might be like "task type: X, nr. of hrs: n, nr. of pieces m". Or even more dimensions, beyond task type, hrs, or pieces. What I was thinking, after I though about it a bit more, is that this resembles more of a Deep Learning exercise, rather than a regression. 
Like: each collection of points in X space (task type, hours, pieces) maps to an expected value of  Y (pay), like a collection of dots in an n-dimensional image mapping to a label, or something...